# how to get second record in linq to sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have an exchange rate table. I need to get current rate and previous rate and then compare results.

I can get first record using `FirstOrDefault`.

When I am using `ElementAtOrDefault`, this error shows "The query operator 'ElementAtOrDefault' is not supported". How can I get the second record?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var query=data.Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Answer (score 9):

Take() returns null if the element is not there (so is equivalent to FirstOrDefault()).

If you'd rather an exception was thrown (cos the second element is not there) like First() then use:

```
Skip(1).Single()
```

Comment: Shameless plug: Use https://www.nuget.org/packages/ByteDev.Collections/ ... if you would prefer to use Second(), SecondOrDefault(), Third() ... etc. style methods. I use them a lot in unit tests :-). These methods also give very consistent exceptions in the same vain as First() / FirstOrDefault(). The project is also on GH and is MIT license.

Answer (score 9):

Try this simple implementation this might be useful

```
var query= (from p in db.Person where p.Person == person_id select p);
var firstResult = query.First();
var secondResult = query.Skip(1).Take(1).Single();
var thirdResult = query.Skip(2).Take(1).Single();
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a detail not explicitly mentioned here: `FirstOrDefault` returns an `Element`, `Skip(1).Take(1)` returns a set of 1 element; i.e. the type returned by `Skip(1).Take(1)` is `IEnumerable`, while `FirstOrDefault` is not.

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
.Take(2)
```

you will get the first and second.

EDIT- If you need both the first and second, then the above will be more efficient than runing your query twice:

```
.Take(1)
.Skip(1).Take(1)
```

Comment: Or Skip(1).Take(1) to get only 2nd.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collection.ElementAt(1)
```

will fetch the second record in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Select top 2, then select second element.

Answer (score 1):

As John Anderson already pointed out `Skip(1).Take(1)` returns an `IEnumerable` of size 1.

In order to get the 2nd entry itself or else a `null` (i.e. no exceptions), I'm using the following:

```
var secondEntry = collection?.Skip(1)?.FirstOrDefault();
```

It may not work in your specific case, but may be useful for use cases of other.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Skip(1) method