# Getting Nth value with Linq

Tags: linq

How can I get the Nth row using Linq? both columns are text so I cant use min/max

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
var nthItem = items.Skip(n).First();
```

Comment: _Skip(int count) count: The number of elements to skip before returning the remaining elements._ So if we skip n, we get nth index not nth element (starting from 1), don't we? Like on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/824652/3958365

Answer (score 32):

An alternative (.Net 3.5 and later) is to use ElementAtOrDefault.

```
var nthItem = items.ElementAtOrDefault(n-1);
```

The method's index is zero-based, so if you want the third element, you pass 2 for the index.

Answer (score 6):

You can use skip and take.

```
var result = myData.OrderBy(<your order by>).Skip(5).Take(1);
```

Comment: Take doesn't return an item, it returns a sequence (with one element in this case).

Comment: @Mark: indeed it does, and I think it's best we've given the OP both options.

Answer (score 4):

```
var nthItem = items.Skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use order by with skip

```
var nthItem = items.OrderByDescending(<your order by>).skip(n-1).FirstOrDefault();
```